# Undefined name 'user' on Profile Page - Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have made signup and login pages, and they work perfect, but now I am trying to create a Profile page, but when I try to add Navigator or put the home in main.dart as Profile page, it doesn't work:

[image: main.dart error]

[image: navigator error]

Main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:mypocket/telas/perfil/Perfil.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
);
  

  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  //  widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Pocket',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
    ),
      home: Perfil(user: user,),
    );
  }
}
```

Perfil.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:mypocket/controllers/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:mypocket/controllers/validator.dart';

class Perfil extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  Perfil({required this.user});

  @override
  _PerfilState createState() => _PerfilState();
}
  class _PerfilState extends State<Perfil> {
  late User _currentUser;
    
  @override
  void initState(){
    _currentUser = widget.user;
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 172, 178),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Perfil'),
        toolbarHeight: 90,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)
          ),        
        elevation: 15,
      ),
    body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is firebase_auth.dart, created to make the authentication of the login and register pages:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FirebaseAuthHelper {

static Future<User?> registerUsingEmailPassword({
  required String name,
  required String email,
  required String password,
}) async {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? user;

  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    user = userCredential.user;
    await user!.updateProfile(displayName: name);
    await user.reload();
    user = auth.currentUser;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      print('The password provided is too weak.');
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      print('The account already exists for that email.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  return user;
}
```

Also, if I remove user: user, it still doesn't work:
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have not created the instance of the `User`. To create that you can create using this.

```
class FirebaseAuthHelper {
 FirebaseAuthHelper._();
 static final instance = FirebaseAuthHelper._();

  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


 Future<User?> registerUsingEmailPassword({
 required String name,
  required String email,
   required String password,
  }) async {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   User? user;

 try {
   UserCredential userCredential = await 
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
   password: password,
);

user = userCredential.user;
await user!.updateProfile(displayName: name);
await user.reload();
user = auth.currentUser;
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
   if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
   print('The account already exists for that email.');
 }
 } catch (e) {
    print(e);
 }
   return user;
 }
```

I would suggest create a singleton class of your `FirebaseAuthHelper` so that you do not need to add a `static` keyword every time you can access any method of the class like this `final auth = FirebaseAuthHelper.instance`.

To access the method you just need to call it like this `auth.registerUsingEmailPassword(parameters)`.

To get an instance of the `User` you can do like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:mypocket/telas/perfil/Perfil.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
 );


  runApp(const MyApp());
 }


  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  //  widget is the root of your application.
  final auth = FirebaseAuthHelper.instance 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My Pocket',
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         theme: ThemeData(
      ),
      home: Perfil(user:auth.firebaseAuth.currentUser),// To get current user 
    );
   }
  }
```

I hope this will help you